# Validate the number of arguments passed in bash from read

Tags: bash, shell

I have a question about validating user input regarding number of arguments passed by the user in a bash script.
For example, if I use:

```
if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]
then...
```

that will check if 2 arguments passed from the command line like this:

```
./somescript.sh arg1 arg2
```

but how to validate if user passed 2 arguments when asked?
For example:

```
echo "Type 2 names:"
read...
if [[ user passed more || less than 2 arguments]]
   echo "incorrect number of names"
```

Now if I try to use `$# -eq 2` it doesn't work.

What's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array:

```
read -r -a array
if [[ "${#array[@]}" -eq 2 ]]; then ...
```

See output of:

```
declare -p array
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively if your shell has no array like ksh or POSIX shell, you can populate the arguments from the read variable like this:

```sh
read -r reply
set -f # Disable globbing
set -- $reply # without quotes
if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
```

Comment: And another way is `read -r name1 name2 junk`, followed by `if [ -n "$junk" ] || [ -z "$name2" ]; then …did not provide 2 names…`.  Yes; I'm a retrograde programmer who doesn't like the `[[` operator.

Comment: An alternative is to do that in a subshell in order to preserve positional parameters, like `if ( set -- $reply; [ $# -eq 2 ] ); then ...`. Be that as it may, if user enters `*` or any matching glob pattern, this will fail miserably

Comment: @oguzismail I added `set -f` to disable globbing, so entering an `*` would not mess with file names.