# How to validate user input on a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I'm creating a bash script. However, I need the script to validate that the user has to enter two arguments. Not 1 and nothing more than 3.

```
echo -n "Enter two values"
read val1 val2
```

Comment: Might help: [Validate the number of arguments passed in bash from read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60909805/3776858)

Comment: *Arguments* aren't read by `read` at all, they're provided by the program that starts your script before it's even invoked.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
    echo "var1: $1 var2: $2"
else
    echo "error: need to set two argument"
fi
```

run:

```
./scriptName.sh first second
```

Comment: `$1` and `$2` should be in quotes themselves. It's more correct to write `echo "var1: $1 var2: $2"` -- look at what happens if instead of `first` and `second` you run `./scriptName "first * argument" "second argument"`; with the expansions unquoted the whitespace-surrounded `*` is replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory. This is the same problem discussed in abbreviated form in [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: ...similarly, while it only matters in very weird corner cases (f/e, if `IFS` contains numeric digits), it's more correct to write `if [ "$#" -eq 2 ]`, or `if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]`, or `if (( $# == 2 ))`. If `IFS=0`, and `$#` is 10, then unquoted it expands to just `1`, whereas quoted it expands to the correct/original value of `10`.